# How i can call functions from other class? Swift, Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a class ACCreateObject. They have a function circlePhysicsDefault.
I want to call this function other file by push the Button.
In GameViewController i type:

```
@IBAction func addOneCircle(sender: AnyObject) {
        ACCreateObject.circlePhysicsDefault(ACCreateObject)
}
```

But i have a issue: '(ACCreateObject).Type' is not convertible to 'ACCreateObject'. How can i call the function?
What am doing wrong?

Thanks!

ACCreateObject.swift

```
class ACCreateObject: SKScene {
    func circlePhysicsDefault() {
        var Circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 40)
        Circle.position = CGPointMake(500, 500)
        Circle.name = "defaultCircle"
        Circle.strokeColor = SKColor.blackColor()
        Circle.glowWidth = 10.0
        Circle.fillColor = SKColor.yellowColor()
        Circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 40)
        Circle.physicsBody.dynamic = true
        self.addChild(Circle)
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your class code?

Comment: Can you post the code of `circlePhysicsDefault` method?

Comment: Added ACCreateObject.

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem. But circle don't add on a GameScene. Can you help me, please? Or i do add one more questions? I past this function in GameScene function didMoveToView and circle has been added on a GameScene, but if i push the button - does nothing :(

Comment: See my comment on my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling an instance method on a class object. You have two solutions :

Create a new instance and calls it's method

```
ACCreateObject().circlePhysicsDefault()
```

OR

Make it a class function

```
// In your class file
class func circlePhysicsDefault() {
    ....
}
```

And then call
    ACCreateObject.circlePhysicsDefault()

Comment: Make your function to return your cirlcle object `circlePhysicsDefault() -> SKShapeNode` and `return Circle` instead of self.addChild. And in your GameScene `var child = ACCreateObject().circlePhysicsDefault()` `self.addChild(child)`

Comment: I've been added this in GameScene, but on my app launch - add one circle. I push the button, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm understanding you right but by what you are saying you want to call a method on the type instead on an object

The first thing that comes to mind is this:

```
var x = ACCreateObject()
x.circlePhysicsDefault()
```

I think this is the way you should do this.I know there are options of making a class circlePhysicsDefault