# Extra argument green in call while using swift

Tags: ios, xcode, string, swift, uicolor

How to accomplish this similar code with swift. However when I tried to accomplish with the swift, it is giving an error Extra argument `green` in call

```
+(UIColor *)colorWithValues:(NSString *)colorValues{
NSArray *colorComponents = [colorValues componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

CGFloat red = [[colorComponents objectAtIndex:0] floatValue]/255.0;
CGFloat green = [[colorComponents objectAtIndex:1] floatValue]/255.0;
CGFloat blue = [[colorComponents objectAtIndex:2] floatValue]/255.0;
CGFloat alpha = [[colorComponents objectAtIndex:3] floatValue];
UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:red 
                                       green:green 
                                        blue:blue 
                                       alpha:alpha];
//UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
return color;
}

bgView.backgoroundColor = [[self class]colorWithValues:@"155,124,144,1"];

    func colorWithValues(#colorToString : String) -> (UIColor) {

    var colorString = colorToString.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
    let redColor : Float = Float(colorString[0].toInt()!)/255.0
    let greenColor : Float = Float(colorString[1].toInt()!)/255.0
    let blueColor: Float = Float(colorString[2].toInt()!)/255.0
    let colorAlpha: Float = Float(colorString[3].toInt()!)

    var colorValue : UIColor! = UIColor(red:CGFloat(redColor), green:CGFloat(greenColor), blue:CGFloat(blueColor), alpha: colorAlpha)
    return colorValue
}
```

Comment: func colorWithValues(#colorToString : String) -> (UIColor) shouldn't the return type be (UIColor *)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see you forgot to wrap `alpha` in `CGFloat`

```
var colorValue : UIColor! = UIColor(red:CGFloat(redColor), green:CGFloat(greenColor), 
blue:CGFloat(blueColor), alpha: colorAlpha)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^ here
```

Which causes the problem, change it to this

```
var colorValue : UIColor! = UIColor(red: CGFloat(redColor), green: CGFloat(greenColor), 
blue: CGFloat(blueColor), alpha: CGFloat(colorAlpha))
```

Comment: Your answer helped. Just a question i have written in func in a helper class .so how do i access this helper class and call this func

Comment: You can call this function as you are calling other function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25528640/how-i-can-call-functions-from-other-class-swift-xcode

Answer (score 1):

You should change your `Float` values to `CGFloat`:

```
let redColor : CGFloat = CGFloat(colorString[0].toInt()!)/255.0
let greenColor : CGFloat = CGFloat(colorString[1].toInt()!)/255.0
let blueColor: CGFloat = CGFloat(colorString[2].toInt()!)/255.0
let colorAlpha: CGFloat = CGFloat(colorString[3].toInt()!)
```

This way you can pass the values without needing to convert them, which can prevent problems such as forgetting to cast the alpha value to `CGFloat`.

Comment: Like this alpha will always be 1 or 0